# UML Sequence Diagram: Can Lost Messages represent calling another diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I'm designing some Sequence Diagrams for my project and decided to divide login and register use cases, creating two different diagrams (thought was a wise choice to separate concerns and simplify).

Now, when Register process is finished, I would like to tell the diagram to follow some path inside Login Diagram. Is that what Lost message is for? Like calling an event outside the diagram? Please clarify.

[image: Lost Message Diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `Gate`. UML 2.5 Specs:

> **17.4.4.3 Gate**
>
> Gates are just points on the frame, the ends of the messages. They may have an explicit name (see Figure 17.4).
>
> **17.12.9 Gate [Class]**
> 17.12.9.1 Description
>
> A Gate is a MessageEnd which serves as a connection point for relating a Message which has a MessageEnd (sendEvent / receiveEvent) outside an InteractionFragment with another Message which has a MessageEnd (receiveEvent / sendEvent) inside that InteractionFragment.